# code blocks don't work in Spyder (Anaconda3)

Tags: spyder

I am a beginner in Python using Spyder to code from Anaconda3.
I tried to enter such codes in Spyder (Python 3.7). I pressed "Enter" when trying to split the codes and the indents appear auto. But it always returns with "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" and "SyntaxError: 'return' outside function".
E.g. 1

```
data = {'state':['Ohio','Ohio','Ohio','Nevada','Nevada','Nevada'],
        'year':[2000,2001,2002,2001,2002,2003],
        'pop':[1.5,1.7,3.6,2.4,2.9,3.2]}
```

When I press F9 in either line, it returns "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".
E.g. 2

```
def f(x):
    return pd.Series([x.min(),x.max()],index=['min','max'])
```

Press F9 to run the line, it returns "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing". If in the second line, it returns "SyntaxError: 'return' outside function".

In addition, I also tried to put "\"s at the end of each line. It doesn't work either. And find from webpages that if the lines end with : or , then you don't need \ to split.

But!!! if I deleted the 'Enters' and put everything in a single line without splits, it works well totally. 
Why my python cannot work with code blocks? How can I fix it with Anaconda3?
Thank you so much~~~~

Comment: can you write the exact code that gives you the error? (a pic might be more helpful, you can load a screenshot in sites like: https://it.imgbb.com/ )

Comment: I have edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need to select the entire function before pressing F9, if you select only a part of it it will raise an error

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\` at the end of each line to tell Python that the line continues below:

```
data = {\
'state':['Ohio','Ohio','Ohio','Nevada','Nevada','Nevada'],\
'year':[2000,2001,2002,2001,2002,2003],\
'pop':[1.5,1.7,3.6,2.4,2.9,3.2]\
}
```

Having the dictionary split across multiple lines may look pretty, but it is not proper syntax. I've also been tripped up by tutorials that show their dictionaries like that :|

This may not work in interpreters other than IDLE.

Comment: I also tried this. It doesn't work either. And find from pages that if the lines end with : or , then you don't need \ to split.....

Comment: @xli what interpreter are you using? Is it IDLE or something else?

Comment: I use Spyder to code from Anaconda3. Do you mean this?

Comment: @xli yeah, thats what i mean. im not sure that Spyder supports splitting code over multiple lines. just put everything on one line or switch to IDLE